# Using environment variables in a file path

Tags: ruby

I want to use an input `path` in the following code:

```
File.exists?(File.expand_path(path))
```

Can I use environment variables in `path`, and what should the syntax be?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. What path do you want? Do you mean load path? That is an array of directories.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Here's what I mean: let's say I have a environment variable MY_VAR and I'd like `path` to be `%MY_VAR%/bin`. This syntax doesn't work, and neither does `$MY_VAR/bin`. Is there a different syntax that should work?

Comment: `ENV['MY_VAR']`, Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard ruby string interpolation (though it's a little bit wordy)

```
path = "log/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log" # or whatever
# >> "log/development.log"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that works for me, because I can't modify the rest of the code, I can only play with the contents of `path`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand environment variables, you should do it yourself:

```
def expand_env(str)
  str.gsub(/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|\${\g<1>}|%\g<1>%/) { ENV[$1] }
end

expand_env("${SHELL}:%USER%:$PAGER")
# => "/bin/bash:amadan:less"
```

(both Windows-style and Unix-style are supported, but only the basic substitution, and not any crazy stuff that bash is capable of).

Answer (score 1):

For portability it is probably best to use `File::join` and `ENV` Hash:

```
File.exists?( File.join(ENV['MY_VAR'],'bin') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Rubocop suggested the following improvements to the answer by @Amadan:

```rb
def expand_env(str)
  str.gsub(/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|\${\g<1>}|%\g<1>%/) do 
    ENV.fetch(Regexp.last_match(1), nil) 
  end
end
```